# component is getting loaded on 2nd iteration in react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-redux

I am using react plus d3 for my graph. now I am merging two different arrays to populate y graph. but one of the array is showing undefined to me, I checked in reducer both array gets the data properly. but if I go and come back again to the page it is working fine. so means only whenever my DOM is clear it is giving me problem.  below is my reducer

```
const VolumeQuantity = MixMergeGroup.map(data => {
        return data.map
          .map(mixdata => mixdata.world_volume * sum)
          .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
      });

      var VolumeQuantityGraph = [];
      var tempObj_world = null;
      MixMergeGroup.map((data, index) => {
        tempObj_world = {};
        tempObj_world['world_name'] = data.key;
        tempObj_world['world_volume'] = VolumeQuantity[index];
        VolumeQuantityGraph[index] = tempObj_world;
      });
var overGraph = [];
      currentYearData.map((data, index) => {
        let temp = {};
        temp.key = data.name;

        let values = {};
        values.value = data.forcasted_volume;
        values.label = data.year + ' Volume';
        temp.values = [values];
        overGraph[index] = temp;
      });
return {...state,overallGraph: overGraph,MixVolumeGraph:VolumeQuantityGraph}
```

here is my component where I use this value

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (
      this.state.graphData.length == 0 &&
      nextProps.MixVolumeGraph !== undefined
    ) {
      nextProps.overallMixData.forEach(function(element) {
        let filtereddata = nextProps.MixVolumeGraph.filter(
          data => data.name === element.name
        );
        element.world_volume = filtereddata[0].volume;
      });

      console.log('nextprops', nextProps);
      this.setState({ graphData: nextProps.overallMixData });
    }
  }
```

can please anyone let me know why on first instance its not giving me any value?

Answer (score 0):

from docs `React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may update. Calling this.setState generally doesn't trigger componentWillReceiveProps.`

so you need to call this method in componentdidmount to start it on first mount

edit: sample:

```
processData(nextProps) {
  if (
    this.state.graphData.length == 0 &&
    nextProps.MixVolumeGraph !== undefined
  ) {
    nextProps.overallMixData.forEach(function(element) {
      let filtereddata = nextProps.MixVolumeGraph.filter(
        data => data.name === element.name
      );
    element.world_volume = filtereddata[0].volume;
    });

    console.log('nextprops', nextProps);
    this.setState({ graphData: nextProps.overallMixData });
  }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  processData(nextProps);
}

componentDidMount() {
  processData(this.props);
}
```

Comment: it is giving me error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` I changed my code to `let filtereddata = this.props.MixVolumeGraph.filter( data => data.name === element.name );`

Comment: you need to add .bind(this)... like `nextProps.overallMixData.forEach(function(element) { ... }.bind(this));`

Comment: or do a `let thisProps = this.props` before everything... and then use `thisProps` not this.props

Comment: hi sorry to ask but u said I need to use `componenetDidMount` so in that how can I use nextProps? can u update u r answer with example

Comment: there you extract that into another method and call it from the two points... sending nextProps and props

Comment: there also it is the same error which I got earlier `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Comment: sorry means "filter"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153155/discussion-between-lowcool-and-uxdart).

Comment: the question you asked was answered, you should open another question with the code in context of this another problem you are having. without seeing code is imposible to know what could go wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had used `componentDidMount` but it was giving me error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` this is because I was using foreach loop. I changed into `map` it is working now below is my update loop

```
this.props.overallWorldMixData.map(data => {
      let filtereddata = this.props.MixVolumeGraph.filter(
        dataName=> dataName.name === data.name
      );
      data.volume = filtereddata[0].volume;
    });
```

I don't know the reason and I know it is not immutable solution, if anyone can clarify this I would be glad

Comment: if you use a function() {} you need to bind it to this like `function() {}.bind(this)` if not `this` inside the function is not the the outside 'this'